# More than one different Injected Instance of an object in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a class like this

```
  import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  @Injectable()
  export class Address {
        street: string;
       ... some other attributes

  }
```

And a class like this

```
  import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Address } from './address';

   @Injectable()
   export class Company {
         name: string;
         constructor(public address: Address) {}
   }
```

And I use the above classes like this

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Address } from './address'; 
  import { Company } from './company';

   @Injectable()
   export class Employee {
      name: string;
      lastName: string;

      constructor(public address: Address,
                  public company: Company) {}
   }
```

Now, I use the Employee class in a component like this

```
  import {Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { Employee } from '../model/employee';

  @Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'my-employee',
   templateUrl: '../views/employee.html
  })
  export class EmployeeComponent {
      constructor(public employee: Employee){}

   ... some other stuff;
 }
```

My questions are:

1.- Why I'm getting the same **Address** object for both the company and the employee address objects?
2.- How can I get different instances of **Address** object?

3.- I know, I can make a new instance of **Address** in the constructor of the EmployeeComponent, with the new operator, and then assign it to the let's say employee.address,  but then, what is the purpose of 
DI in Angular 2?

Comment: I mostly use injection for services in Angular. For example if you had an Address Service then it would make more sense to inject it. Then it also makes sense that you get the same instance injected (the same instance will be injected for the entire module per default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.- Why I'm getting the same Address object for both the company and the employee address objects?

That because you're using the same injector. Injector tree maps the component tree, which means that each component has it's own injector and it will try to resolve its dependencies using it, and if that's not possible, it will bubble up the resolution up to the root injector. In this case, since you haven't included your models in component providers (your injector is essentially empty) it will use root injector and pass the same instance of your injectables all over the application. Step by step:

1. Your EmployeeComponent constructor requests Employee injection
2. Request bubbles up to the root injector (there is nothing in component injector)
3. Injector tries to create new Employee
4. Employee constructor request Company and Address injection
5. Injector creates new Address
6. Injector tries to create Company
7. Company requests Address injection
8. **Injector injects already resolved Address object from step 5.**
9. Injector creates Company
10. Injector creates Employee
11. Injector injects Employee into the Employee component

NOTE: Having injector on the component level won't help - it would still be the same address for all objects where Address is injected inside that components scope.

> 2.- How can I get different instances of Address object?

You might want to take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472103/create-new-instance-of-class-that-has-dependencies-not-understanding-factory-pr/38473200#38473200). Also, you can take a look at the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#usefactory).

> 3.- I know, I can make a new instance of Address in the constructor of the EmployeeComponent, with the new operator, and then assign it to
>   the let's say employee.address, but then, what is the purpose of DI in
>   Angular 2?

The purpose is as same as in any other language. It might not be clear, as interfaces are not used in a same way as in C# or some other language, but the point is to reduce the dependency on behaviour from some concrete object to abstract object that can be injected into the class at runtime. It's not meant for POJOs, data contracts and, in most cases, business domain model. It's meant for classes that excercise behaviour that can be abstracted and injected into a number of different software components, so they can use this behaviour in runtime, but not depend on it's concrete implementation.