# How can I get new instances of a class using Injector instead of singleton

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have two injectable classes in my angular application

```
@Injectable()
class B {}

@Injectable()
class A {
  constructor(b:B) { }
}
```

I want class A to be Singleton and class B to be Transient

I came to know I can use **ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate** in class A to get an instance of class B. Any better way of achieving this ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472103/create-new-instance-of-class-that-has-dependencies-not-understanding-factory-pr/38473200#38473200 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482357/angular2-how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-same-service/38483406#38483406

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all existing recipes for providers create singletons, even factory, you can create your own injector, inherit all providers from component injector and use [resolveAndInstantiate](https://angular.io/api/core/ReflectiveInjector#resolveAndInstantiate) method to get new instances every time:

```
import { Component, Inject, Injector, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';

class P {
}

const ps = [];

class C {
  constructor(@Inject(P) p) {
    ps.push(p);
  }
}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    const parent = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([P], injector);
    const child = parent.resolveAndCreateChild([C]);
    const c1 = child.resolveAndInstantiate(C);
    const c2 = child.resolveAndInstantiate(C);
    console.log(c1 === c2); // false

    console.log(ps[0] === ps[1]); // true

  }
}
```

[Here is the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdzz7y?file=app/app.component.ts).

Also bear in mind that `ReflectiveInjector` is deprecated in @5.x.x. And it seems that there's no alternative in the new [StaticInjector](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-introduces-staticinjector-should-you-care-4e059eca030c). I reported [an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18946) about that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Maxim. I have a question though , can't we use a regular factory method which returns a new instance of required object when needed ?Secondly isn't ReflectiveInjector deprecated ? Do you still recommend to use it

Comment: @SRK, no, the factory doesn't return new instances every time, whatever it returns the first time it caches it. So even if you do `return new AClass()` inside you will still get a singleton

Comment: @SRK, also, bear in mind that ReflectiveInjector is deprecated. And it seems that there's no alternative in the new StaticInjector. I [reported an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18946) about that. You can read more about StaticInjector [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-introduces-staticinjector-should-you-care-4e059eca030c)

Comment: Thank you . I was under the impression until now that a factory returns a new instance every time I call it .

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to solve this using StaticInjector and functional Javascript. Using Max Koretskyi answer, with few modifications I come up with this:

```
import { Component, Inject, Injector } from '@angular/core';

class P {
}

const ps = [];

function pFactory() {
  return () => new P();
}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  providers: [{provide: pFactory, deps: [], useFactory: (pFactory)}],
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(@Inject(pFactory) pf) {
    let fn = pf.get(pFactory)
    ps.push(fn());
    ps.push(fn());
    console.log(ps[0] === ps[1]); // false
  }
}
```